# CakePHP, triple equal signs misunderstanding

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi I'm making some tutorial with CakePHP and I got stuck when I look at if statement.

Please look at the if statement with triple equal signs.

```
class Item extends AppModel{
protected function _processFile(){
    $file = $this->data['Item']['file'];
    if($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
        $name = md5($file['name']);
        $path = WWW_ROOT.'files'.DS.$name;
        if(is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name']) &&
            move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$path)){

            $this->data['Item']['title_img'] = '/files/'.$name;
            unset($this->data['Item']['file']);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

Here is my question

why the if statement when makes error uploading the file executes the rest of the codes to upload the file?

Should the rest of the codes placed at "return false;"?

Please let me know what i missed to understand the if statement.

Thank you guys

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `why the if statement when makes error uploading the file executes the rest of the codes to upload the file?` ? Is it executing the upload whilst there is an upload-error? And which error did you try?

Comment: Please rephrase the question. I have trouble understanding the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry to confuse you with my question. The question was that I thought the first if statement determine error while uploading as true. But I misunderstood the statement because of UPLOAD_ERR_OK which i thought it was error as true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basic php and not related to CakePHP: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php and this link as well http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php.

```
$a == $b    Equal       TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.
$a === $b   Identical   TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.
```

You're doing a comparison based on the type, try == instead of ===. php is not a strict typed language that's why we have == and ===.

Some extras:

- Instead `$this->data['Item']` use `$this->data[$this->alias]` in models.
- Follow the [CakePHP coding conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html)
- You should not just check if the file was uploaded but also handle the error cases

And if you don't want to re-invent the wheel you can checkout my [FileStorage](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage) plugin or take a look at it's code.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that === is to determine type. Thank you so much

Comment: I recommend you to read about the basic operators of the php language then. ;) There is more. Would you mind flagging my answer as correct? Thank you.

Comment: can I ask you one more question about the if statement? What does $file['error'] mean? where is error from? how $file['error'] can be identical to UPLOAD_ERR_OK? Thank you

Comment: Try to search and read the manual, it explains *all* these basics. Here is the link to the main page for file uploads. http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php The 2nd link there explains all possible error codes. A good amount of time as a programmer is spent by reading and writing documentation. And the php language has a very good documentation compared with others. :)

Answer (score 1):

`UPLOAD_ERR_OK` is equal to 0 and actually means there was no error when uploading the file.

Comment: So the UPLOAD_ERR_OK type is string and the value is 0?

Comment: UPLOAD_ERR_OK is not a string, but a constant defined by the PHP team. The goal is to make the code easier to understand for other developers.

Answer (score 1):

`this === means that $file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK` have same type.
Do they have same ? or perhaps $file['error'] is a string.

try with 2 egals.